# Post appeared in Suggested edit even though there are no visible changes

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits, specific-edit

I found this while reviewing Suggested edits:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13263766

I couldn't find a single character of difference and also no higlights in either side of the post (original and edited), but still it appeared in the review queue and the user who edited says "please approve my edition".

Okay, I understand I can simply skip it or reject, but my question is: If there are no changes at all, how can such a post appear in the Suggested edit queue?

[image: Rendered output view]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The "markdown" toggled view shows that this was just whitespace being removed.

As such It's a candidate for rejection as "no improvement".

Comment: Thank you for the details, but I used to see there were a tiny Highlighter for even a single space change.